# Bash check for file

Tags: shell

I have this piece of code to check if a file exists in a directory, but it exits saying the file doesn't exist -

```
# in another file in the same directory
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
source "${SCRIPT_DIR}/common.sh" # calling the code below
```

```
BACKUP_VARS_FILE=${BACKUP_VARS_FILE:-"${SCRIPT_DIR}"/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh}
if [ -f "${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}" ]; then
    source "${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}"
    echo "Using vars file: '${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}'"
else
    error "'${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}' not found"
    bail "You should create it using '${SCRIPT_DIR}/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh.example' as a template"
fi
```

But the file does exist in the same folder as `common.sh` where the code is.
[image: screenshot of file being in the same location]

Output - it doesn't even go in the if/else block

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any help please?

edit -
Variable output, reading the file (with less) works -
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: maybe check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142338/shell-script-error-to-check-if-file-exists

Comment: echo the SCRIPT_DIR to check if you have the right path. paste it here because it may be the problem

Comment: Thanks for your response, added it in the edit

Comment: What is the output of echo ${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}? what about echo ${SCRIPT_DIR}?

Comment: This was the output
back up vars - `/home/ubuntu/backup/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh`
Script dir - `/home/ubuntu/backup`

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example of your problem? it is hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I will post a new question which better explains the issue. I feel like I'm way too in over my head..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the output is "/bitbucket...", without anything before the slash, I think your `${SCRIPT_DIR}` is empty, which makes it looking for the file laying under root directory `/`.

Your current directory is `/home/ubuntu/backup`, where can find `bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh`, but your script may looking for `/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh`, not `/home/ubuntu/backup/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh`. Check `${SCRIPT_DIR}` variable first.

Comment: I made an edit to show how it is indeed looking in the right directory (on top of the first code block)...  send help please. `${SCRIPT_DIR}` was declared in another file

Comment: Also, yup that was a problem and I updated it, but the script still fails

Comment: @Teh__docco I think you may mis-simplifying your question. Is the 11985 bytes have something returning earlier?

Comment: You're right! Sorry will close this and post a better question.